# Linked List made with 2 structs. Access node

Tags: c, pointers, struct, linked-list

I am trying to learn the basics and, who would have thought, pointers are killing me. I want to create a basic linked list. for this, i created two structs, a linkedList which has 3 pointers, one for the first node, one for the current node and one for the last node. I hoped this would enable an easier inserting of new nodes.
Then i have nodes, which are just a value and a pointer to a new node.

```
typedef struct linkedList linkedList;
struct linkedList{
    struct node* start;
    struct node* last;
    struct node* current;
};

typedef struct node node;
struct node{
    int value;
    struct node* next;
};
```

I create a new Node with

```
node* newNode(int value){
    node* newNode = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
    newNode->next = NULL;
    newNode->value = value;
    return newNode
}
```

Now, in the main, i create a new linked list with

```
linkedList List;
List.start = NULL;
List.current = NULL;
List.last = NULL;

node* node1 = newNode(1);

List.start = node1;
List.current = node1;
List.last = node1;
```

Now, how do i access the content of the nodes by using the linked List?
If i do it how i would have done it in Java, the compiler says 
"error: request for member 'value' in something not a structure or union"
if i try

```
List.start.value = 1;
```

if i try

```
(*(List.start)).value = 1;
```

it compiles but gives me a segmentation fault.
I am not sure about the way pointers work, really. The linked lists i found with google all used just nodes, no main linked list to interact with. I was pretty much thrown into the deep end for a school course, so the knowledge i have about the intricacies of c are limited.

Comment: you need a book.

Comment: @Jim Johnson  List.start->value = 1;?

Comment: @Jim Johnson  And show the minimal code that demonstrates the problem with the segmentation fault.

Comment: @JimJohnson.: It shouldn't... you can post full code.(unless your malloc failed)

Answer (score 0):

What you did is something like `N` independent nodes each of them knows about the first node, last node and itself.

You said you wanted to create a linked list? Get any hint? Where is the link?You must connect them together to form a data structure which will make access more easier.

So I will give you an overview of standard way we do these things. You will have some reading to do.

What you want to implement is something called `Doubly linked list` where each node knows about two of the others, one that is before it and another which is after it.

Now that makes it easier to insert node and delete it.

struct node {
    int data;
    struct node * next;
    struct node * prev;
};

Now you need to create a doubly linked list, you will do something like this in `main()`

```
struct node*head= malloc(sizeof(struct node));
if( head == NULL){
    fprintf(stderr, "%s\n","Error in malloc" );
    exit(1);
}

insert(head, data);
...
..


void insert( struct node * head, int data){
    struct node*temp= malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    if( temp == NULL){
        fprintf(stderr, "%s\n","Error in malloc" );
        exit(1);
    }
    temp->data = data;
    temp->next = head;
    temp->prev = NULL;
    head = temp;
}
```

Also delete the doubly linked list after you are done working with it.

How you can do it....

```
linkedList List;
List.start = NULL;
List.current = NULL;
List.last = NULL;

node* node1 = newNode(1);

List.start = node1;
List.current = node1;
List.last = node1;
```

Now at this point if you want to access `node1` you would do it like this

```
(*List.start).value = 1;
```

Or

```
(List.start)->value = 1;
```

#### Explanation of the first error:-

`List.start.value` is basically trying to find the value field over the address of the `node1`. Compiler has no idea how to get it from a non-structure or non-union element.

A small demo of what I said about your last error:-

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct linkedList linkedList;
struct linkedList{
    struct node* start;
    struct node* last;
    struct node* current;
};

typedef struct node node;
struct node{
    int value;
    struct node* next;
};
node* newNode(int value){
    node* newNode = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));

    if( newNode == NULL){
       fprintf(stderr,"error in malloc");
       exit(1);
    }
    newNode->next = NULL;
    newNode->value = value;
    return newNode;
}
int main(){
    linkedList List;
    List.start = NULL;
    List.current = NULL;
    List.last = NULL;

    node* node1 = newNode(1234);

    List.start = node1;
    List.current = node1;
    List.last = node1;
    printf("%d\n", (List.start)->value);
    printf("%d\n", (*List.start).value);// this works

}
```

Comment: @JimJohnson.: I ahve shown a sample code where I access elements just like you did..check the code. It might help

Comment: @JimJohnson.: With your idea or way of implementation you can't end up with good managable code..You need a doubly linked list or so

Answer (score 0):

```
    List.start.value = 1;
```

The above won't work. `List.start` will give `node1`, so next you need to do `node1->value` because node1 is pointer of structure type.

So use the below statement:

```
    (List.start)->value = 200;
```

Or you can use it like this too:

```
    (*(List.start)).value = 200;
```

Test these with this:

```
    printf("accessing : %d\n", node1->value);
```